# C++, help extending this class

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm to extend a C++ class, but have absolutely no background in that language. Googling didn't help me understand how to solve the compilation error:

```
Constructor for 'JRB2World' must explicitly initialize the base class 'b2World' which does not have a default constructor
```

So, there is this b2World.h

```
class b2World
{
public:
    b2World(const b2Vec2& gravity);
    ~b2World();

    // ...
```

And its .cpp:

```
b2World::b2World(const b2Vec2& gravity)
{
    // ...
}

b2World::~b2World()
{
    // ...
}
```

My class header:

```
#import "Box2D.h"

class JRB2World : public b2World {

    float factor;

public:

    JRB2World(const b2Vec2& gravity);
    ~JRB2World();

    float getFactor();
    void setFactor(float f);
};
```

My class implementation:

```
JRB2World::JRB2World(const b2Vec2& gravity) {

// Constructor for 'JRB2World' must explicitly initialize the base class 'b2World' which does not have a default constructor
}

JRB2World::~JRB2World() {
}

float JRB2World::getFactor(){

    return factor;
}

void JRB2World::setFactor(float f){

    factor = f;
}
```

I suppose it has to do with a call to the "super constructor" like in java or objc. How can this be done?

Comment: when you don't have a default constructor in the base class (b2World), you need to call the base class constructor with argument explicitly from the derived class constructor's member-initialization list (JRB2World).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put the constructor into the initializer list of the inherited class' constructor:

```
JRB2World::JRB2World(const b2Vec2& gravity) : b2World(gravity) {
}
```

Depending on what you want to do, I wouldn't use inheritance here: Put the Box2D world into a member variable. That should make it easier to replace it, just in case its interfaces changes over Versions or you decide to use another physics engine later on.

Answer (score 1):

You base class doesnt have default (without arguments) constructor. Call it in derived class initialization list:

```
JRB2World::JRB2World(const b2Vec2& gravity):b2World(gravity) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would favour composition over inheritance for this example.

Using composition you can always choose to define your own behavior or simply expose that of your your composed parts. This way you face none of the restrictions that may be imposed by an inheritance hierarchy (virtual vs. non-virtual etc.) You might not need access to all the b2World methods in your new class